# HTML Printing Problem of absolute positioned element

Tags: html, css, printing

I am trying to print a simple HTML but facing issue after print. Print preview is showing okay but when printed on paper there print extra margin of 2mm on top & left, also left & right side being cut of about 4mm and bottom is being cut of about 2mm.

Please check my html and css below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            html, body {
                font-size: 15pt;
                font-weight: bold;
                overflow: visible;
            }
            #ReportTable {
                border-collapse: collapse;
                border-spacing: 0;
                width: 279mm;
                height: 89mm;
                background: yellow;
                table-layout: fixed;
                float:right;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%; 
                left: 0%;
                transform: translate(0%, -50%);
            }
            
            #ReportTableParent2, #ReportTableParent1 {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
            
            *  { margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important; border: 0 !important; } 
            

            @media print {  
                header {
                  display: none;
                }
                html, body {
                    overflow: visible;
                }
                @page {
                    size: 279mm 89mm;
                    margin: 0;
                }
                
                *  { margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important; border: 0 !important; } 
            }   
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="ReportTableParent2">
            <div id="ReportTableParent1">
                <table id="ReportTable">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr style="height: 30mm;">
                            <td style="width: 100mm;">
                                <div><span>aaa</span></div>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 120mm;">
                                <div><span>bbb</span></div>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 59mm; text-align: right;">
                                <div><span>ccc</span></div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr  style="height: 20mm;">
                            <td style="width: 100mm; background:green;">
                                <div><span>ddd</span></div>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 120mm; background:white;">
                                <div><span>eee</span></div>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 59mm; background:gray; text-align: right;">
                                <div><span>fff</span></div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also check the screenshots:

[image: Design]

[image: Print preview]

[image: What actually being printed on paper]

I am not getting any clue that what I've done wrong!